# Did the way to connect to a MongoLab database change?

Tags: python, mongodb, ibm-cloud, mlab

I have a Bluemix app that has a MongoDB instance bound to it. The app had been running for about a year. About a week ago, my app went down and I'm unable to redeploy it. I'm seeing the following in the log:

```
 Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
App instance exited with guid f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd", "version"=>"1c5aeea8-2718-48ff-9d89-211148391cc8", "instance"=>"5673b51557b3457f8b3e365639fe7f6f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1445263465}
App instance exited with guid f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd", "version"=>"1c5aeea8-2718-48ff-9d89-211148391cc8", "instance"=>"5673b51557b3457f8b3e365639fe7f6f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1445263465}
Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd
App instance exited with guid f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd", "version"=>"1c5aeea8-2718-48ff-9d89-211148391cc8", "instance"=>"5673b51557b3457f8b3e365639fe7f6f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1445263465}
Starting app instance (index 0) with guid f13c5665-7753-4451-b766-b0879b3726fd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "wsgi.py", line 65, in <module>
 client = pymongo.Connection(mongo_url)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 220, in __init__
max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 369, in __init__raise ConfigurationError(str(exc))
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'removingForPrivacy'), ('nonce', u'removingForPrivacy'), ('key', u'removingForPrivacy')]) failed: auth failed
```

My code is available in my project at https://hub.jazz.net/project/lhayward/Fabulous%20Price%20Finder/overview. Has the way to connect to a MongoLab instance changed? Why am I getting authentication errors?

Answer (score 4):

I e-mailed with MongoLab support. They replied:

> Our free Sandbox databases recently went through the scheduled version
>   upgrade event described at:
>
> http://docs.mongolab.com/20150930-maintenance-event/
>
> We sent several notices on this planned maintenance over the past few
>   months.
>
> This Sandbox database is now running MongoDB 3.0.x, which includes
>   changes to MongoDB's authentication mechanism. This new mechanism is
>   supported by certain newer driver versions, as described at
>   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-drivers.
>
> In order for your application to connect to this database, you will
>   need to use one of the drivers listed at the above link.

They made the following suggestion for my app, and it fixed the problem:

> You'll have to update the "mongo-python-driver-master" folder to a
>   more recent version of the python driver. You can download the driver
>   here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/releases. I'd
>   recommend either version 2.9 or 3.0.3.